# Client side javascript SDK for Docusign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I have been looking for a way to make API calls to the Docusign REST API using strictly client-side javascript (no Node). I haven't been able to find a single example of how to do this which leads me to believe it's not possible for some reason.

Furthermore I haven't seen an SDK for client side javascript calls. Only the following are available: C#, Java, Objective C, Node, PHP

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#sdk-docusign

So my question is this, is it possible to make purely client side calls to the Docusign API?

Comment: Hoping to reopen this question. If all we're doing is sending a document, and then DocuSign will ask the user to log in, it seems like a good way to provide simple integration. Basic use case: A public terms of service document with a link: "Click here to sign with DocuSign", and it opens in their account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not fully from a client side, due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) restrictions for security purposes.

Comment: I'd also mention leaking the integrator key and/or credentials (depending on use case).

Comment: @JeffKyllo very true, lots of risks here :(